Moving from tomcat9 to tomcat10, system still tries to load javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
My servlet used to work on tomcat9. I try to use tomcat10.
I removed javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar from my build path and added jakarta.servlet-api-5.0.0.jar.
I changed any reference to javax.servlet in my code:
//import javax.servlet.*;
//import javax.servlet.http.*;

import  jakarta.servlet.*;
import  jakarta.servlet.http.*;

So far I am still importing javax.mail and javax.crypto, but I will change this later if necessary and possible.
I use ant to build my project and javac successfully creates classes in the webapps folder of my tomcat10 installation:
destdir="/var/lib/tomcat10/webapps/${app_version}/WEB-INF/classes"

But the servlet will not start, with the following in localhost.2024-06-27.log file:
27-Jun-2024 15:23:00.211 SEVERE [https-openssl-nio-8080-exec-198] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log HTMLManager: Error starting [/tomcat_app]
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tomcat_app]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1312)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:656)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:205)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:190)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:333)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:304)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 33 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
        ... 67 more

The whole project is long and complicated. It seems that there is a class that still tries to load javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.
How to find out which class, or more generally, which part of my code or configuration is still trying to load javax/servlet/http/HttpServletload?
edit:
I found out that one of my classes extends class com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet. The class com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet and this may be a problem. Perhaps I should use com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.jakarta.RemoteServiceServlet instead. I see that this is in gwt-servlet-jakarta.jar. So far, I have not been able to find where to download gwt-servlet-jakarta.jar. Is it too early to use GWT together with Tomcat10?

Is it available publicly?

It is not publicly available, but I can share here any file that may be related to the issue.

Thinking out of the box, you could try setting up a dummy maven project with the dependencies in it that you are manually managing through the ANT build and run a mvn dependency:tree on it to see what transitive dependencies are being pulled in. If any of them rely on old javax dependencies, those are likely sources of the problem.

Use [code block] format for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

The problem seems related to how the application is built. You should provide the script and class path used. Why are you targeting the tomcat directory instead of building a war?

It's not clear what you asking. We don't know what tools are you using and not able to suggest you anything. But searching for javax.servlet in your source files should give you immediate results. The exception cannot be analysed because you have posted incomplete stacktrace. Search server logs for details. If you want to learn How to resolve ClassNotFoundException the you should read the link.

Tomcat 10.0 is end-of-life. Are you using Tomcat 10.1? Edit your Question to be specific.

Thanks to all for the help. I edited my question with info about what the problem might be. Basil: Tomcat is 10.1.16. Aled: I edited my question and put the log in code block. I am using gwt and javac to share the same object on client (javac/class) and server (gwt/javascript). Yes, I am targeting the tomcat directory. I may have to change this but I do not think it is directly related to the issue. Roman: the workspace does not contain the text "javax.servlet". Yes, I am sharing incomplete stacktrace. Getting tomcat to output the complete stacktrace could answer my question, maybe.

One of my classes extends class com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet that implements javax.servlet.Servlet. I Changed the extension to com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.jakarta.RemoteServiceServlet included in the jar file I donwloaded here: https://repo.vertispan.com/gwt-snapshot/org/gwtproject/gwt-servlet-jakarta/2.11.0-jakarta-SNAPSHOT/
I hope this self-answer will help someone else with the same problem.

Also see https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9727.

And https://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_11_0
